# validator is undefined in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-form-validator

I have a bootstrap modal containing two radio button: the first one contain a form and the second contain a kendo grid. I have to chose to create a new object from the form or to select an existant object from the grid
To be able to select an existant object from the grid I disabled the validation from the form like this:

```
<div >
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.xxxxx)
                    <div >
                        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.xxxx, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And then to make my validation work  when creating a new object from the form I used a fuction to tests if form proprities are empty or not like this:

```
if (xxx== '') {
            alert("  le champ xxx est obligatoire");
            return false;
        }
```

Every thing is doing right and I get my object correctly but when I open my firefox console I have an error message like this :

TypeError: validator is undefined
    settings = validator.settings;

I didn’t know what is the cause of this error !!
Please help me.

Comment: Have you set ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to true in the appSettings section of web.config? Also, have you referenced jquery, jquery.validate, and jquery.validate.unobtrusive?

Comment: @Andy Nichols ,yes i have set ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to true in the appSettings section of web.config and for the referenced jquery i have put section Scripts { <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script> <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script> <script src="/js/libs/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> } but even that the error is displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell from your question, but is the modal in question loading a partial view? If so you may need to add the script declarations at the top of the partial view page, even though they are included in the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when my validating element was not a `<form>`. It looks like jQuery Validate needs to be called like `$('form').validate()` or more precise selector but identifying only `<form>`.